# Smallest Sum Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I feel like I may not have been clear enough about the requirements so let me try to make things more clear.

You are provided a dictionary that contains keys that are either single letters or multiple letters. Each key has an associated value. Given an input, you must find the keys that contain the input letters. Return the lowest key values that satisfy this requirement.

Here are a few examples:

Input Dictionary

Key -> Value

a -> 4

b -> 6

e -> 5

abc -> 8

---

Input: 'a'
Output: 4

Input: 'c'
Output: 8

Input: 'ab'
Output: 8

Input: 'ac'
Output: 8

Input: 'ce'
Output: 13

Input: 'd'
Output: null

Note on the third example, the input is ab. So here, we can either get the letter 'a' from the key 'a' or the key 'abc'. We can either get the letter 'b' from the key 'b' or the key 'abc'. In order to get both keys with the lowest total value, 'abc' with a value of 8 is the correct output.

Note on the fifth example, the input is ce. The letter 'c' is only available in the key 'abc'. The letter 'e' is only available in the key 'e'. The correct output in this situation is 13.

UPDATE: I was able to solve this recursively by starting off with the first letter in the input sequence, finding all keys that contain that letter, and for each key, building a list of all the possible combinations. I was able to track the lowest sum by recursively moving through one letter of the input sequence at a time.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a [perfect question.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) Also, be sure to take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Edited to show what I'm currently trying and stuck on.

Comment: how was abc value of 8 determined, is that simply its value, or do you have to look at a,b and c to determine its value and end being highest.

Comment: If you're given an input of letters, you find the lowest sum of key values containing all of the letters given. In this case, the input was a and b. We can either get the value of them individually (10), or in this case, there's a key containing both with a value of 8. Therefore we choose 8 because it is the option with the lower sum. We ignore the c in this case as extras can be ignored if it means a lower sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and probably should do recursion. Always grab the next letter of the string you are searching for, and continue building all the possibilities. For each branch, keep just the smallest value and the string it is associated to.

Starting with letter a, you have 2 options - either [4, a] or [8, abc]. Now you continue to the next letter, for a you now have [6, b] or [8, abc]. As this is the end of the list, and b is smaller than abc, you end up with [10, ab] here. Now the other, abc branch, can skip b - it already has it. So, you compare [8, abc] vs [10, ab] and abc is smaller, so it gets returned. And is the final solution already.

Comment: I ultimately solved it using recursion. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

What I am suggesting here is a bit long method but this is what i can think of to help you right now
Take a max count variable 
Now if the input is multiple letters check for all the strings who have the required alphabets. Also look for "sum of alphabets" separately.

Keep on updating the max_count variable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                       
  import operator

    def smallest_sum(dic):
        a_dic = {}
        b_dic = {}
        # get a list of all keys containing a and b
        for key in dic:
            if "a" in key:
                a_dic[key] = dic[key]
            elif "b" in key:
                b_dic[key] = dic[key]

        a_dic = sorted(a_dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        b_dic = sorted(b_dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

        if "ab" in a_dic[0]:
            return a_dic[0][1]
        else:
            a_sum_b = a_dic[0][1] + b_dic[0][1]
            return a_sum_b

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        dic = {"a":2, "b":3, "abc":10, "ab": 15, "bcd": 2}
        sum = smallest_sum(dic)
        print(sum)
```

Comment: check for edge cases, like if list is none

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i get it right

```
private static Dictionary<string, int>  dic=new Dictionary<string, int>()  ;
public static void MinSum()
{

    // here create statements where the key is a single letter
    dic.Add("a", 4);
    dic.Add("b", 6);
    dic.Add("c", 3);
    dic.Add("d", 4);
    dic.Add("e", 5);
    // here add the combination
    dic.Add("abcde", 8);
    dic.Add("abce", 10);
    dic.Add("ae", 2);

    var minSum= GetMinSum( "ae".ToCharArray());
    var minSum2 = GetMinSum("abc".ToCharArray());
    var minSum4 = GetMinSum("a".ToCharArray());

}

public static int GetMinSum(char[] letters)
{
    //If the input is a single letter, then I simply return the value associated with that key
    if (letters.Count() == 1)
        return dic[letters[0].ToString()];

    // sumUp all the single Key elements
    var sumOfSingleKeyElements = dic.Where(x => x.Key.Length == 1 && letters.Contains(x.Key[0])).Sum(v => v.Value);
    // get the min value Key elements that combine the letters above
    //  the " !letters.Except(x.Key.ToCharArray()).Any()" defines if the set letters is a subset of the key
    var minOfCompositeKeyElements = dic.Where(x => x.Key.Length > 1 
                        && !letters.Except(x.Key.ToCharArray()).Any()
                        ).Min(v => v.Value);

    return sumOfSingleKeyElements < minOfCompositeKeyElements ? sumOfSingleKeyElements : minOfCompositeKeyElements;
}
```

- The minimum sum for the letter combination "a","e" is 2
- The minimum sum for the letter combination "a","b","c" is 8
- The minimum sum for the letter "a" is 4

Comment: I actually had this exact solution at first but ran into an edge case. Let's assume it's a mixture of singleLetterKeys and multipleLetterKeys. For example, if the input is a and b, there can be the following keys: a = 4, bc=6. The value returned should be 10.

Comment: Hi. Your requirement is to compare the sum of the single letter keys with the values of the composite keys and return the smallest. In my example, if you call the function with "ab" you will get back the value 8 of the key "abcde"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify my requirements well enough then. This isn't a comparison between the sum of single letter keys and the composite keys. The minimum sum can be a combination of one or the other, or both. If you can get the minimum sum by using one single letter key with one composite key, then that is allowed as well.

Comment: There is a contradiction here because in your original post you mention  _So here, 'a' and 'b' separately have a sum of 10. Whereas 'abc' which includes both, has a sum of 8. I want to return 8._ and also in your last comment of the original post you confirm this requirement. In my example for letters a & b: **a** =4, **b** =6 so sum=10. The key **ab**cde contains both with the value of 8. Also key **ab**ce contains both but the value is 10. So the return result should be 8. What am i missing here?

Comment: For your example, 'a' should return 2 as it can be obtained from 'ae' with a value lower than it can be obtained from 'a' by itself. Also, consider the input 'ce' which should return 5. This is what I mean by we don't have to obtain the letter from EITHER single keys or composite keys. It can be a mixture of both, whatever has a lower total. I have updated my original question to be more clear.

Comment: in your clearer and updated question does the Input: 'ac' should have  Output: 12(?) and not 8 because it falls on the same category with the input 'ce'? _The letter 'c' is only available in the key 'abc'. The letter 'a' is only available in the key 'a'. The correct output in this situation is 12 (??)_